# Is it ok to run whole PHP application in a MySQL transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

Is it ok to run whole PHP application in a MySQL transaction?

Is there any side effects?

I mean something like this:

1. Client requests A.php
2. A.php -> start mysql transaction
3. A.php -> execute and process request
4. A.php -> commit mysql transaction
5. send requested data to client

Comment: You describe one task beeing in a single transaction

Comment: This is not running the *whole PHP application* in one transaction, but each request in a separate transaction, and that's fine if you know what you are doing (locks, long lasting transactions, ...): but in essence the same concepts apply in a pure SQL engine based (stored procedure) solution.

Comment: Side effects: implicit commit, dead locks .. - I would just not want to worry about wich side effect i didn't take in account.

Comment: Just a question from an old fashioned CGI programmer: Isn't the transaction closed (auto-rolled back) when the script ends? Or are transactions and connections persistent between script calls?

Comment: @PerlDog As far as I know, PDO's transaction automatically commits at the end of execution and there is not a concern on persistent connections, anyway, we call commit/rollback commands at the end of script ourselves, so there is no problem at all.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That's what I had expected. At first sight I thought you wanted a single DB transaction from, say, the user's login until his logout. For hours in the extreme. And thinking of my CGI scripts I had doubts that this would even be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call this *running the whole PHP application in one transaction*, but rather a PHP script that treats each request in a separate transaction.

That is fine, as long as you are aware of transaction related concepts, such as locking, deadlocks, starvation, ... In essence, you should like in any other environment not lock database objects longer than necessary, prefer fine grained row locks over full table locks and protect your database against deadlocks.

But as those same concepts apply in a pure SQL engine based (stored procedure) solution, there is no particular reason not to do this in PHP.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for selecting bad words to describe my question, English is not my mother tongue. I had same concept that you described in my mind.